# React update dynamic nested state

Tags: reactjs

I have data object as

```
let d = {
    'items': [
     {'item':'apple', price: 200},
     {'item':'banana', price: 300},
    ],
    tot:[2],
    'shop': 'xyx shop',
    'customer':['a','b','c']
    }
```

i am getting it from an api call and setting it to a state. Like this

```
const [state, setState] = useState({})

useEffect(
{
setState(d)
},[])
```

Here how can I update the price?

I have tried this

```
setState({...state, items[index].price - 1});
```

It's not working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy the `items` array from `state`
2. Change the data
3. Override the `items` array

```js
let index = 1;
let newItems = [ ...state.items ];
newItems[index].price++;
      
setState({ ...state, items: newItems });
```

Example:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const SameSet = () => {

    const [state, setState] = useState({
        'items': [
            {'item':'apple', price: 200},
            {'item':'banana', price: 300},
        ],
        tot: [ 2 ],
        'shop': 'xyx shop',
        'customer': ['a','b','c']
    });
    
    const update = () => {
     
      // Index to update
      let index = 1;
      
      // Copy
      let newItems = [ ...state.items ];
      
      // Bump
      newItems[index].price++;
      
      // Override
      setState({ ...state, items: newItems });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={update}>Click me to update!</button>
            {state.items.map(i => <em>{i.item}{' -- '}{i.price}</em>)}
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<SameSet />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
div { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: technically, you are mutating item when you do `newItems[index].price++;`. when you create a copy from items array you still have the same old object references that array contains. you should create a new copy from the object you are updating with new price value.